# Problem installing MikTex 2.9 on Windows 10 (64 bit)

Tags: miktex

I've been trying to install MikTex on my Windows laptop but I keep getting the same error after all the directories seem to install. The error log looks like this:

```
... extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
    extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
    extracting files from zapfding.cab...
    updating package definition directory ("C:\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
    installed 2989 package definition files
    visiting repository C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\mik1932...
    repository type: local package repository
    loading lightweight database...
    "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe" --user-install="C:\MiKTeX 2.9" --log-file="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose:

    An error occurred:
      source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
      source line: 159
      message: The executed process did not succeed.
      info: fileName="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe", arguments="--user-install="C:\MiKTeX 2.9" --log-file="C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose", exitCode="-1073741792"
```

I have tried many of the recommended fixes (uninstalling Adobe, checking the permissions for .pdf in the Windows registry, installing outside of Program Files but in a new folder in C:/, turning off firewall). I'm doing it as the administrator so I don't see how that's a problem. But I get the exact same error message every time.

Comment: It is difficult to see why it fails. But as all packages have been installed: Did you try if you can run pdflatex?